# Object-c memory alloc IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, alloc

I have a problem with memory full with RNDecryptor (+)  in a cycle "for" i call this method es:

```
for (int i=0;  i < [datasource fileCount]; i++) {
    ...
    datacrypto = [RNDecryptor decryptData:datacrypto withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:passcode error:nil];
    ....
}
```

RNDecryptor allocates memory but the calls do not empty and sooner or later there is no more free memory and CRASH ... its possible dealloc +[RNDecriptor...] between calls or otherwise as a solution ??

thank you.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're trying to decrypt too much data in memory. What do you do with the `NSData` you get from that method?

Comment: then : [datacrypto writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), fileName] atomically:YES]; ...

Comment: i have resolved with :

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Code that creates autoreleased objects.
    }

bye.

Comment: @Marino ...and you're presumably on top of why that resolves the problem? Or would an answer still be helpful, regardless of the fact that you already know the fix?

Comment: @Tommy the problem is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the implementation of the method.

```
+ (NSData *)decryptData:(NSData *)theCipherText withSettings:(RNCryptorSettings)settings password:(NSString *)aPassword error:(NSError **)anError
{
    RNDecryptor *cryptor = [[self alloc] initWithPassword:aPassword
                                            handler:^(RNCryptor *c, NSData *d) {}];
    cryptor.settings = settings;
    return [self synchronousResultForCryptor:cryptor data:theCipherText error:anError];
}
```

It's no a singleton or is there any other branch? If not, you better implement your own `singleton` pattern.

Comment: Ok, no no (correct) decryptData it's not singleton !

Comment: i have resolved with :

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Code that creates autoreleased objects.
    }

bye.